# .mp4 can be accessed normally outside blender but I can't make the sound work on blender vse preview or even render a video with audio

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, file-format, audio

Pretty much self explanatory. As you can see in the screenshot, I am using a configuration that used to work really well in the past. But now it does not work anymore with this .mp4 file that I got from Shadowplay recording. When I access the file outside of Blender, it works well, but if I insert it on Blender, it does not work the audio on VSE preview... If I render it under the setting displayed, it also will not have any audio on it.

Anyone can help me?

[image: no audio on preview or after rendering]

Comment: Some screen capture apps create files with variable frame rate. Most likely you are going to need to transcode your file using a codec with intraframe encoding and a constant framerate. The VSE is a very outdated tool, if you must use it, then you need to conform  conform your video to a video format that is the exact framerate as your project. As an alternative try editing in a different (more modern) video editing app

Comment: Ffmpeg, which is used to import video has been updated in the latest 2.90 beta, so try that version of Blender out.

Comment: @susu Is there any good video editing app out there without watermarks or similar? Blender is quite reliable although it is less "friendly" on VSE. I like the fact that it is free to use it.

Comment: @susu I tried to use handbrake and made it a constant framerate. Didn't solve my problem but I managed to get my video done with a giant watermark. But what to you mean by "intraframe encoding"? Sorry, I don't know exactly what it means. About the rest of your message, I guess I did what you said. And, tinwotin I will make sure to update it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find folks giving you advice and make you jump through hoops and walk through fire just to get your video to play in blender, but the bottom line is that Blenders VSE is a very inefficient and antiquated program. Why put yourself through a poor experience when there are better, friendlier and responsive programs out there? Transcoding shouldn't be necessary in today's software and hardware. Try shutcut, DaVinci resolve free, openshot, media composer first, premiere, etc etc. A search in your favorite search engine for free or cheap video editing sotware will give you plenty of choices. Be happy, stay creative. Don't be bogged down by the tools. Make the tools work for you, not the other way around. Blenders is great for creating 3d, but not a great video editor.

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvotes were accompanied by arguments.

Comment: It has nothing to do with age or coding, if the screen capture is recorded with a variable frame rate then Blender is not "designed" to deal with it. Simply put Blender expects 1 frame per frame. Blender DOES NOT DO temporal awareness, anywhere. It doesn't do frame blending because it expects event to happen at frame change. If the CODEC doesn't change frames then its a poor fit for Blender. But you're still right... just use Resolve.

Comment: Indeed, @pointedit, It was mentioned in the first comment. Most folks would not know that, or how to fix it, not do they want to spend time learning the intricate ways of video encoding. They just want to get their video done. Blender is not the tool for all needs. Being free doesn't make it a useable tool for today's needs. I'm just advocating for saving users a sour experience with Blender's less developed tool.